# Get out of "orange selection" mode

Tags: interface, selection-tools

All the objects in my scene are suddenly circled with a dark orange stroke.
I can't seem to modify, delete or even select some of them...

Just a beginner at Blender, but I couldn't get an answer anywhere I looked.

[image]

Comment: I never saw this before, odd. You must have hit some specialized key shortcut

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you can't select other objects is because you are in *[Edit Mode](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/introduction.html#edit-mode)*.
The reason for the orange outlines is likely due to having entered edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) while all objects were selected (<kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

While in edit mode, you can edit the mesh of the *Active object*, but cannot move any other objects. To select a different active object for editing, you'll have to first toggle back to [*Object Mode*](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/introduction.html) (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) before clicking an object with <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>.

Also see the [blender manual](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/selecting.html).

Comment: I don't know if that's what it was, I got out of it by deleting objects in the scene overview> I think everything became orange when I tried to copy and paste a shape instead of duplicating it (cmd + c / cmd + v).

Comment: When you paste object from buffer they are all selected by default.

Answer (score -5):

While in object mode, you need to select all the objects and click Object > Join or ctrl + J