# How do i select an object that is separated from other objects

Tags: texturing, selection-tools

I was watching a tutorial on texturing. There was shown a way to separate the glass part of the windows so you won't keep on clicking on them while you're texturing which I admit made things a lot easier.

Now I want to work on texturing my windows but I have no idea on how to select them. They aren't on a different layer. If there is a clip board option on here I haven't found it yet.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the problem you're facing. Please provide a link to the tutorial (point out the moment you're stuck on) and preferably add some screenshots with your current scene demonstrating problem. If you mean you have 2 separated objects and you'd like to edit the other one exit Edit mode of current one with `Tab`, select desired object and `Tab` to enter Edit mode for that one.

Comment: Possibly related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38881/get-out-of-orange-selection-mode

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for Face selection mode? http://i.imgur.com/XjYTJI9.png

Answer (score 0):

Because you mention the object is separate from other objects, I am thinking that selection may have been disabled on the object you can't select.

In order to enable/ disable selection on an object you can click on the arrow next to the objects name in the *outliner*.

[image]